# Mostrar datos mas actuales en un datagridview

Tags: c#, datetime

Al momento de darle clic al radiobutton "Actual" quiero que en el datagridview **solamente** se me muestren los datos **mas actuales** de la linea que yo seleccione en el combobox. Cuando corro el programa me da el siguiente error: Incorrect syntaxis near '11-28-16'. En un principio intente tomar la fecha del datetimepicker pero me daba el mismo error. Como puedo solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

```
    private void btnFiltrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rbTodos.Checked) {

            conexion.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CWS where Family = '"+cbLine.Text+"' and Date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'and'" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'", conexion);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(DS, "CWS");
            dataCWSreport.DataSource = DS.Tables["CWS"];
            conexion.Close();
        }

        if (rbActual.Checked){

            String fecha;
            int fecha1 = lblShowDate.Text();
            fecha = lblShowDate.ToString();
            conexion.Open();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CWS where Family = '" + cbLine.Text + "' and Date '" + lblShowDate.Text + "'", conexion);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(DS, "CWS");
            dataCWSreport.DataSource = DS.Tables["CWS"];
            conexion.Close();
        }

    }
```

PD: el tipo de dato de la columna Date es 'date'.

Comment: ¿Cómo llenas lblShowDate.Text?

Comment: Con el siguiente codigo que coloco en el load de la ventana:

             DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            string fecha1 = dt.ToString("d", ci);
            String format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
            String str = dt.ToString(format);
            lblShowDate.Text = str;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al dar clic al `RadioButton` `actual` ordena la consulta de forma descenciente:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM CWS WHERE Family = '" + cbLine.Text + "' and Date = '" + lblShowDate.Text + "' ORDER BY [Date] DESC", conexion);
```

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error de sintaxys cerca del '28-11-16'.

Comment: Te falta el signo igual luego de Date "="

Comment: @fredyfx es correcto amigo, faltaría el signo de igual

Comment: Muchas gracias si era eso.

Comment: de nada hermano, acabo de editar la respuesta con el signo = agregado :D

Answer (score 0):

Que tal amigo, e tu consulta `da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CWS where Family = '"+cbLine.Text+"' and Date between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'and'" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'", conexion);` veo que el formato de tu fecha es el siguiente: MM/dd/yyyy 
Y en tu Datagridview es: 23-Nov-15
Verifica en tu base de datos como se guarda el Date, puede que sea una cuestión de formato de fechas. Saludos

Comment: En mi laptop asi se muestra la fecha con ese formato. Se debera a eso?

Answer (score 0):

Usa el formato sin esacios para fechas "yyyyMMdd" en el ToString de tus DateTimePicker y así no te marcará error.

Comment: A mi modo de ver, deberías editar tu pregunta e incluir un ejemplo de lo que comentas. Piensa que esta respuesta puede solucionar el problema de gente con pocos conocimientos si dedicas unos minutos a completarla correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma factible es con un `TOP` en tu consulta, este sirve para limitar las filas y no sobrecargar de datos tu grid, también ordenando las fechas de mayor a menor, mira:

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 5 FROM CWS where Family = '" + cbLine.Text + "' ORDER BY [Date]DESC",conexion);
```

Esto te puede funcionar también, aunque yo no le colocaría un `TOP`.